# Что означает число перед хэшом в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, password-hash

Что означает число перед хэшом в Wordpress?
Пример: 1550060128:$P$BENUhadNnkdknOycEqmGMSRZ3dxGFd.

Comment: соль ?.........

Comment: Или время. Если это timestamp, то это `Wed Feb 13 2019 12:15:28 GMT+0000`